# Setting up value for node within nsmutabledictionary having array within it

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios6

this is  structure of data in json format

```
{
 "12122012":[
   {"date":12/12/2012 10:45, checked:YES},  
   {date:12/12/2012 11:45, checked:NO},
   {date:12/12/2012 12:45, checked:YES},
   {date:12/12/2012 13:45 , checked:YES}
 12112012:[
   {date:12/11/2012 10:45, checked:YES},  
   {date:12/11/2012 11:45, checked:NO},
   {date:12/11/2012 12:45, checked:YES},
   {date:12/11/2012 13:45 , checked:YES}]
}
```

we  have to change the checked value TO NO for 12112012:[0].checked =NO how is this possible
?

Comment: Is your desired output is as                                         {
 "12122012":[
   {"date":12/12/2012 10:45, checked:YES},  
   {NO},
   {date:12/12/2012 12:45, checked:YES},
   {date:12/12/2012 13:45 , checked:YES}
 12112012:[
   {date:12/11/2012 10:45, checked:YES},  
   {NO},
   {date:12/11/2012 12:45, checked:YES},
   {date:12/11/2012 13:45 , checked:YES}]
}

Comment: {
 "12122012":[
   {"date":12/12/2012 10:45, checked:YES},  
   {date:12/12/2012 11:45, checked:NO},
   {date:12/12/2012 12:45, checked:YES},
   {date:12/12/2012 13:45 , checked:YES}
 12112012:[
   {date:12/11/2012 10:45, checked:NO},// here is the change  
   {date:12/11/2012 11:45, checked:NO},
   {date:12/11/2012 12:45, checked:YES},
   {date:12/11/2012 13:45 , checked:YES}]
}

Comment: {date:12/11/2012 10:45, checked:NO},this is the change I amexpecting in the given result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have NSMutableArrays in your NSMutableDictionary for that.

Comment: I am reading this data @ once into a nsmutabledictionary .I am expecting a direct method like we do with keypath for setting up value

Comment: It is not likely to be. What I could recommend is to replace NSArrays with NSMutableArrays in you dictionary by hands since you cannot change any of usual NSArray's elements.

Comment: Is there any wrapper , so that it could be changed like [dctObj objectforArrayKeypath@"12112012[0].checked"] =NO;  I expect apple should add this feature

Comment: May be. Depends on your JSON parser. SBJSON is not likely to have it.

Comment: If you use NSJSONSerialization you can use NSJSONReadingMutableContainers option for it to provide mutable containers in your JSON object. Than you can edit it